# CSS transition to target scale only

Tags: css, css-transitions

The following css zooms in an element with class `modal` when the class `open` is applied. At the moment the transition is targeting `all`, how can I change this so the modal only animates on scale and not on width change?

```
.modal {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

.modal.open {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1)
    width: 600px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vbsc/

Comment: creat a fiddle please or post html code

Comment: you can use `transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s`, however you can't target only scale transform, such as if you also have `rotate` transform, it's also transitioned.

Comment: @M.chaudhry, fiddle added.

Comment: @KingKing - any other way of achieving this?

Comment: you want to just transition the `scale`, so that's the only way, about the effect you want, I'm not sure what it is, because from the demo, transitioning only `scale` results in a weird effect.